# Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor doesn't get value

Tags: regex, jmeter, load-testing

I have a problem.
I am using Regular Expression Extractor in Jmeter. I have two regex.

I can get the value from this.

```
Reference Name: as_fid_addtobasket

Regular Expression: <input type="hidden" name="as_fid" value="(.+?)" />

Template: $1$
```

But i can't get the value from this one.

```
> Reference Name: DynamicTempOrderProductGuid 
> 
> Regular Expression: <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The
> TempOrderProductGuid field is required."
> id="OrderProducts_1__TempOrderProductGuid"
> name="OrderProducts[1].TempOrderProductGuid" type="hidden"
> value="(.+?)" />
> 
> Template: $1$
> >
```

Here is my result. The second one doesn't get the value. Where is the thing i missed?

> POST data:
>   OrderProducts.index=1&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.TempOrderProductGuid=%24%7BDynamicTempOrderProductGuid%7D&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.Count=1&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.ReceiverModel.OrderReceiver.NameRec=Test+ama%C3%A7l%C4%B1d%C4%B1r.+L%C3%BCtfen+dikkate+almay%C4%B1n%C4%B1z&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.ReceiverModel.OrderReceiver.PhoneRec=05352233285&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.ReceiverModel.OrderReceiver.OSSendingReason=&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.ReceiverModel.OrderReceiver.OSReceiverAddressType=&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.ReceiverModel.OrderReceiver.CompanyNameRec=&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.ReceiverModel.OrderReceiver.AddressLineRec=Test+ama%C3%A7l%C4%B1d%C4%B1r.+L%C3%BCtfen+dikkate+almay%C4%B1n%C4%B1z&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.ProductCode=se213&OrderProducts%5B1%5D.TempOrderProductGuid=%24%7Btokentoken%7D&totalProducts=1&as_fid=efWZ0i4RGLmC2nBWk%2FA1

Comment: You really shouldn't try to parse HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454 . Consider a parser solution instead, especially if you have weird bugs :)

Comment: First of all, you have a `"` in the middle of your `data-val-required` attribute. This may or may not be adversely related to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) instead as regular expressions are pretty dependent on layout, attributes order, spaces, etc. and can be a real headache to develop and test for non-experienced used. Especially multi-line ones.

XPath expression for extracting value from `as_fid` input will look like:

```
//input[@id='OrderProducts_1__TempOrderProductGuid']/@value
```

Some clues:

1. If you're using JMeter 2.11 you'll be able to test your XPath expressions right in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener
2. You may need to check "Use Tidy" box in XPath Extractor if your HTML isn't XHTML compliant
3. Check [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) for language reference.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri! I got the value of my second xhmtl script using xpath extractor. This is my solution. //input[@id='OrderProducts_1__TempOrderProductGuid' and @data-val='true']/@value

Answer (score 0):

Try this simpler regex for your second case:

```
<input.+?value="(.+?)"\s*/>
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/nI8nZ9

Answer (score 0):

You can update the regex as the followings to get the valid `DynamicTempOrderProductGuid`

```
Reference Name: DynamicTempOrderProductGuid 
Regular Expression: name="(.+)"\stype="hidden"value="(.+)"
Template: $2$
```